# Strsplit multiple delimiters r

Tags: r, data.table

i want to split this genomic coordinate : `chr1:713625-714625`

to have only the start coordinate : `713625`

I tried this command :

```
data.table(unlist(lapply(data$gene,function(x)unlist(strsplit(x, [:]))[2])))$V1
```

but it gives me this : `713625-714625`

Do you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried these 2 commands and both of them gives me the same result :

```
gsub(".*[:]([^.]+)[-].*", "\\1", string) by Quinten

data.table(unlist(lapply(data$gene,function(x)unlist(strsplit(x, "[:-]"))[2])))$V1
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there when using `strsplit`, but should use `[:-]` or `:|-`

```
> unlist(strsplit("chr1:713625-714625", "[:-]"))[2]
[1] "713625"

> unlist(strsplit("chr1:713625-714625", ":|-"))[2]
[1] "713625"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code extracts everything between the `:` and `-` in the string:

```
string <- c("chr1:713625-714625")
gsub(".*[:]([^.]+)[-].*", "\\1", string)
```

Output:

```
[1] "713625"
```

Comment: A slightly different alternative pattern is: `".*:(.+)-.*"`